# Очистка консоли для интерфейса Golang

Tags: golang, консоль

Есть ли на Go что то вроде cls как на C++, пробовал искать, но каких то простых решений не нашел, хотелось бы очищать выводы после ввода пользователя, чтобы было легче работать с программой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891644/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-go

Так же под windows можно включить это

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Пример:

```
var (
    kernel32       = syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    setConsoleMode = kernel32.MustFindProc("SetConsoleMode")
)

func SetConsoleMode(m uint32) error {
    r, _, err := setConsoleMode.Call(uintptr(syscall.Handle(os.Stdout.Fd())), uintptr(m))
    if r == 0 {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func Gotoxy(x, y int) {
    fmt.Printf("\x1b[%d;%dH", y, x)
}

func ClearScreen() {
    fmt.Print("\x1b[40m")
    fmt.Print("\x1b[2J")
}

func HideCursor() {
    fmt.Print("\x1b[?25l")
}

func ShowCursor() {
    fmt.Print("\x1b[?25h")
}

func ClearAll() {
    fmt.Print("\x1b[!p")
}
int main() {
    SetConsoleMode(windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING | windows.ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT)
}
```

С помощью ansi escape codes можно так же устанавливать цвета, управлять курсором, и шрифтами. Смотрите ссылку выше.